# Is there a simple hashing router in akka?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am using Consistent Hashing in my Actor System. The problem I am facing is that the keys are not getting distributed evenly (which I expected, though). I was just wondering if there's a Simple Hashing router in akka which I can use.

Or should I implement a custom router?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own router logic by creating a class that extends the [RoutingLogic](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.5/index.html#akka.routing.RoutingLogic)class and override its "select" method. Then you can create a new router with that logic by doing

```
new Router(new CustomRoutingLogic())
```